# google chrome crashes when loading images

Tags: linux, google-chrome

good day, I'm having the problem that google closes when loading some images, or when hovering over them to zoom, the error is closing, I have to manually reopen it.

Has this happened to anyone else?

I already tried disabling hardware acceleration.

My system is: Linux 5.15.0-46-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 4 18:03:25 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Versión 105.0.5195.52 (Build oficial) (64 bits)

Thanks.

Comment: Please share where this happens.  Is it the browser, then a URL.  I desktop, then some properties of the image.

Comment: the log says that. [2611959:2611985:0901/205943.843370:ERROR:broker_posix.cc(40)] Recvmsg error: Connection reset by peer (104)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: for example: "https://www.mercadolibre.com.ar/google-chromecast-with-google-tv-de-voz-4k-8gb-snow-con-2gb-de-memoria-ram/p/MLA16233185# searchVariation=MLA16233185&position=1&search_layout=stack&type=product&tracking_id=69cdea70-a4ff-4c2e-b94e-a84808e6a95a" on this page, when you want to open the image or hover over it, it zooms. closes.